# program output of a c program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

please explain the output of the below mentioned program. I thought that output should be 1 but it is not 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int  a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);

    printf("%d ", *(ptr-1));
    getchar(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `output should be 1 but it is not 1`...so what is it?

Comment: You may want to include more information, including the actual output you received.

Comment: type of `&a` is `int (*)[6]`. it meant pointer to `int[6]`. so `&a + 1` point to next(`a[6]`)  the last element(`6`:`a[5]`). then cast to `int *` then `-1` so point to last element `6`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `&a` has type `int(*)[6]` and hence `&a + 1 != &a[0] + 1` which is what you meant, given your expected output.

If you print the addresses `&a` and `&a[0]`, they will be the same, however incrementing `&a` is not the same as incrementing `&a[0]` because `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`, although that's not always true, your code should not assume it is, or depend on that.

Also, it appears that your are using the cast because your compiler was complaining about the fact that `&a` is of an incompatible pointer type, you should not need the cast if the pointers are of compatible types so

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int  a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int *ptr = &a[0] + 1;

    printf("%d\n", *(ptr-1));

    return 0;
}
```

should compile just find, and the output will be `1` as you expected.

Comment: The downvoter seems to disagree, I would like to see your answer to see if mine is really wrong or bad.

Comment: i am having the confusion around the same thing.. can you please elucidate it little more

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. Would be interested to see the downvoter comment on their reasoning.

Comment: More precisely, `&a` has type `int(*)[6]` (now fixed, thanks). Also, `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` -- `sizeof (int*)` is irrelevant. What's relevant is `sizeof (int[6])`.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `&a` are the same value,
`a` is of type `int [6]`,
`&a` is of type `int (*)[6]`.

It means that

```
    ptr
 == (int *)(          &a + 1                )
 == (int *)( (char *) &a + 1*sizeof(*&a)    )
 == (int *)( (char *) &a + 1*sizeof(a)      )
 == (int *)( (char *) &a + 1*6*sizeof(int)  )
 == (int *)( (char *) a  + 1*6*sizeof(int)  )
 == (int *)( (char *) a  + 1*6*sizeof(*a)   )
 == (int *)(          a  + 6                )
 == &a[6]
```

thus

```
*(ptr-1) == *(a+5) == a[5] == 6
```

the reason why "6 " is printed.